# オープンソースプロジェクトの始め方

Tags: github, oss

オープンソースプロジェクトを立ち上げて開発を行いたいのですが、どのようにして始まり、どのようにして参加者がつくのでしょうか?

誰か1人がプロジェクトの管理者として存在し、その人を中心に数人のチームがあってスタートするのでしょうか。

また、現在はGitHubでソースを公開するのが主流なのでしょうか。

オープンソースが生まれてからどのようにしてメジャーになっていくのかという過程を教えて下さい。

気をつけることや準備しておくべきことなども教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 10):

「[オープンソースソフトウェアの育て方](http://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873114125/)(Producing Open Source Software)」の一読をお勧めします。[日本語訳は広く公開されています](http://producingoss.com/ja/)。オープンソースソフトウェアとは何か、またその歴史が理解できる内容になっており、プロジェクトを持つにあたって気をつけることと、進め方の指針が書かれています。日本語訳を小難しくしておらず丁寧なのがお勧めできる理由でもあります。（日本語で読める物として、他に「[オープンソースプロジェクトの管理と運営](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=WLGbIglW93QC&dq=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%81%A8%E9%81%8B%E5%96%B6&source=gbs_navlinks_s)(Managing Open Source Projects)」がありますが、こちらは内容ががつがつしていて、講義だけで使う教科書のようです。）

GitHub を使ってソースコードを公開することは最近の流行であって、 GitHub の利用が必須なことではありません。

イメージをつかみたいとお考えであれば、[件の本](http://producingoss.com/ja/)を読みつつ、実際のプロジェクトがどのようしているのかを見て回るのが良いと思います。